# Sharing a common internet on 2 PC

Tags: router, internet-connection, modem, connection-sharing

I am using a cable broadband from my provider which gives me a single connection with a RJ45 plug. This is inserted to my desktop and Internet is working fine. But few days ago I purchased a laptop and now wanted to share my Internet on laptop.

I have brought a D-link Modem-cum-Router (Wireless N150 ADSL2+Modem Router) , 
Model => DSL 2730u  To do so. But I came to know that since this is ADSL modem, it expects RJ11 connection. It has one input RJ11 socket which I think I can't use since I have RJ45 connection. And it has 4 RJ45 output sockets. When nothings worked,  I just plugged my RJ45 Internet cable to 1st output and and connected my desktop to the second output. My desktop works and Internet is fine. But I just can't do the same for my laptop also. I am using Windows 7 on both the systems.

I thought in the same way if I connect my laptop to the 3rd RJ45 output, it will also connect as my desktop did. But it is not working.

Am I doing something wrong.?

Please help me as I knows nothing about networking and relies on mercy of you experts.

Answer (score 2):

What you bought was a modem and router combination device. I looked up the device you bought and unfortunately you cannot use it for your purpose.

The reason for this is because you bought a DSL modem/router. This device expects to be hooked up to your phone line directly, which is where a DSL internet service is served from. It will not accept a cable connection, and it does not allow you to hook your cable modem up to it, either. What you will need to do is return it to the store and purchase just a wireless router. Make sure it is not a router/modem combination device, but just a wireless router.

A typical router will have four ethernet ports on the back, and one "Internet" port. You will have to hook the router up to the modem. What the router will do is take the Internet connection from your modem, and basically serve it up to any computer you connect to it.

Whatever router you purchase probably will have an easy setup guide to step you through the process. Some may have a CD that will help you configure things automatically for you. I personally am a fan of Linksys products, but some people also like Netgear. Either one should do you well.

The basic setup that you will have should look something similar to this:
[image: Network layout]

What you will have is have your modem hooked up just like you do already, but instead of plugging your modem directly into your computer, you will plug it into the "Internet" port on the back of the router. You then will plug your computer into one of the "Ethernet" ports on the back of the router. You then will want to configure the router's wireless settings to enable security (password protection and encryption) and name your wireless network. This is actually easier than it sounds, especially if the router came with a setup CD that has a wizard program that helps you through the process.

After you get all that squared away, everything should be up and running the way you want.